# where to connect the offset nulls in a comparator circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, offset

[image]I made this circuit but no matter what the input Voltage is, the output stays high and the led lights. Is it because of the offset voltage ? And where to connect the offset nulls to make the output zero? It did not work when I connected the to ground [image]

Comment: What LED? Use the schematic editor to create a complete and accurate depiction of what you built, and also we need to know the input voltage range you applied.

Comment: What are "offset nulls" ? (I know what you mean but I want you to explain better what you want). There is no **LED** in the schematic. What is the circuit supposed to do? A 741 is an **opamp** not a comparator. Connect what to ground? Also go read: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp/304634#304634

Comment: i am sorry i forgot to say i fed the output to a led . what do u mean it is an op amp not a comparator ? can't it work as a comparator ? and if it doesn't what should i use instead

Comment: Gh, if you don't show us the whole circuit, or at least the while *relevant* circuit, we are forced to guess what it going on. The output is "fed" to an LED. That could mean many different things. Just show it with a diagram.

Comment: i put the simulation of the circuit just as i did it

Comment: Don't use a 741, that's about the worst choice you could make, _especially_ for a comparator.

Comment: Your two schematics are not the same. The one you used in the simulation is extremely unlikely to work, the other one clearly does.

Comment: i didi the two circuit but u say the second one should work but it doesn't . i just read that the 741 can be used as a comparator and wanted to try but i think it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ideal opamp-based comparator multiplies its input difference (V<sub>diff</sub> = V<sub>i-pos</sub> – V<sub>i-neg</sub>) by its open-loop gain (A<sub>o</sub>).

But there's always a non-zero offset voltage (V<sub>os</sub>) which should be added to V<sub>diff</sub>. So the actual comparison equation turns into V<sub>out</sub> = A<sub>o</sub> (V<sub>diff</sub> + V<sub>os</sub>). This equation tels us that;

- If V<sub>diff</sub> +V<sub>os</sub> if greater than zero then V<sub>out</sub> will hit the positive supply rail.
- Likewise, if V<sub>diff</sub> +V<sub>os</sub> is lesser than or equal to zero then V<sub>out</sub> will hit the negative supply rail.

Thus, even if V<sub>diff</sub> is zero then the output will hit either negative or positive rail depending on the sign of V<sub>os</sub>.

---

As for your question, since the output hits to the positive supply rail when V<sub>i-neg</sub> = 6 VDC regardless the value of V<sub>i-pos</sub>, the source of the problem shouldn't be the offset voltage.

You may try adding a potentiometer to zeroe the V<sub>os</sub> like following anyway:

[image]

Comment: then what could be the problem ? and can't i realy use the 741 as a comparator ?

Comment: The biggest problem is to use 741 even in 2019! Anyway, to have the comparator outputting high the positive input terminal should be greater than 6VDC. But you say `no matter what the input Voltage is, the output stays high`. So it's clear that the problem is not about Vos. I suggest you to use a different, modern-day opamp (e.g. LM358).

Comment: and if i use the lm358 the circuit will work ??

Comment: @Gh-B most likely, yes. Please note that you should never leave the positive input floating.

Comment: what do u mean by floating ?

Comment: @Gh-B "floating" means "connected to nowhere". At least place a resistor (e.g. 10k) between positive input and the ground. This prevents the comparator to pick up *(because of extremely high input impedance)* noise from outside world.